# exception - java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException

Tags: java

I'm working with nio (non blocking mode).

when the server is down, and I'm trying to connect (after I'm getting `isConnectable` key) i'm getting the following exception: `java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException`.

Every 1 second, I'm trying to reconnect to the server (via connect method) and getting the same exception: `java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException`.

When the server is up , I'm getting the same exception and cant connect to the server.

1. I don't understand why I'm getting the exception when later the server is ON ?
2. How can I solve it, (How can I try to reconnect to the server ?)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The *SocketChannel* is closed. You closed it, in your code, and then continued to use it. Or possibly you overlooked a `ConnectException`.

Comment: Hi, 1. I didnt close it.    2. when I check isOpen I'm getting true